# Wait for all ajax calls to end before showing SweetAlert2 Toastr mixin

Tags: javascript, ajax, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using the code below to show a notification after an ajax request

```
const Toast = Swal.mixin({ toast: true, position: 'top-end', showConfirmButton: false, timer: 3000 });

//ajax call
$.ajax({
    .....
    success: function(response){
        reloadpanel1(response.id);   //another ajax call
        reloadpanel2(response.id);   //another ajax call
        Toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: response.message,
            customClass: { popup: 'adjust' }
        })
    }
})
```

The problem is that the notification pops up even before `reloadpanel1` and `reloadpanel2` finish their requests.
Is there a way where the `Toastr` won't fire if all ajax calls are not yet finished?

EDIT:

`$(document).ajaxStart()/.ajaxStop()` will not do since the notification message depends on the json `response.message` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a neat solution for my problem using the jquery [when function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
const Toast = Swal.mixin({ toast: true, position: 'top-end', showConfirmButton: false, timer: 3000 });

//ajax call
$.ajax({
    .....
    success: function(response){
        $.when(reloadpanel1(), reloadpanel2()).done(function(){
            Toast.fire({
               type: 'success',
               title: response.message,
               customClass: { popup: 'adjust' }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to try async await

```
const Toast = Swal.mixin({ toast: true, position: 'top-end', showConfirmButton: false, timer: 3000 });

//ajax call
$.ajax({
    .....
    success: async function(response){
        await reloadpanel1();   //another ajax call
        await reloadpanel2();   //another ajax call
        Toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: response.message,
            customClass: { popup: 'adjust' }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry. But this doesn't seem to work. `reloadpanel1` and `reloadpanel2` are functions containing ajax calls.

Comment: then you have to try Promises inside reloadpanel1(); and reloadpanel2();

Comment: function reloadpanel1 {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('foo');
};

Comment: Can you please give me a more elaborate example? Thanks

Comment: can you please share one function here?

Comment: Something like that please check syntax too
function reloadpanel1 { return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve('foo'); };

Comment: Your request is asynchronous thats why this is happening

Comment: `function reloadpanel1(id) {
    var data = { id: id}
    $.ajax({
        url: '/main/upto/process', type: 'post', cache: false, data: data,
        success: function (res) {
            $('#processingpanel').html(res);
        }
    })
}`

Comment: function reloadpanel1(id) { 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var data = { id: id} 
        $.ajax({ url: '/main/upto/process', type: 'post', cache: false, data: data, success: function (res) { 
            $('#processingpanel').html(res);
            resolve(res) 
        } 
        }) 
      });
}

Comment: Use this one with async await on function

Comment: Thank you very much. Will be back after trying your approach.